# Is it possible to setup weekofyear() mode in hadoop hive?

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, hive

I have a table in Hadoop filesystem with a date column. The problem is that when I call the `weekofyear(date)` function, where `date = '2014-12-30 09:17:10'`, it returns `1`. I totally understand why this is so, but I need `52/53` instead `1`.

MySQL has a [`week()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function, where you can pass an argument `'mode'`. And this function with right `'mode'` argument works as I need.

Is it possible to make *mysql-like* function in Hive or make some configuration on the Hadoop server, so that `weekofyear('2014-12-30 09:17:10')` will return `52/53`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you write your **own function** and load it to hadoop in jar format and register it. More about it you can read [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/DropFunction). Good luck!